# Ruby Checking to see if website exists

Tags: ruby

Ok i am checking to see if my server is running. It works as long as the port is correct. But if I cange the port to one I know is not excepted it completely skips my if routine. The example below works fine. But change the port number to say 99 and it completely skips the if. I would think it should fall into the else section.

```
url = URI.parse("http://www.google.com/")
url.port = 80
req = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
res = req.request_head(url.path)

if res.code == "200"
    #do something
else
    #do something else
end
```

Comment: There seems to be too many `else`s there

Comment: It looks like you have one too many `else` statements there. Are we missing something?

Comment: An `else` like that would be valid inside the context of a method definition, but it only triggers if no exceptions are fired. It's probably not what's intended here.

Comment: @tadman But it will say a warning if there are no `rescue`

Comment: @KARASZIIstván Right you are, you'll get: `warning: else without rescue is useless`.

Comment: Sorry I had remenets of other code. I adjusted the code in my first post. And that code works unless port is changed.

Comment: Could you expound on "resuce" and give an example. I am still learning ruby.

Comment: It's actually "rescue", not "resuce".  Google around for things like "ruby exception handling" and ask another StackOverflow question if you get stuck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should provide a *timeout* and rescue `SocketError` and `Timeout::Error`:

```
require "net/http"
def check_server(server, port)
  begin
    http = Net::HTTP.start(server, port, {open_timeout: 5, read_timeout: 5})
    begin
      response = http.head("/")
      if response.code == "200"
        # everything fine
      else
        # unexpected status code
      end
    rescue Timeout::Error
      # timeout reading from server
    end
  rescue Timeout::Error
    # timeout connecting to server
  rescue SocketError
    # unknown server
  end
end
```

If you just want to check if your server is up, this can be simplified:

```
require "net/http"
def up?(server, port)
  http = Net::HTTP.start(server, port, {open_timeout: 5, read_timeout: 5})
  response = http.head("/")
  response.code == "200"
rescue Timeout::Error, SocketError
  false
end
```

It returns `true` if `/` returns a `200` status code and `false` otherwise, i.e. for other status codes, timeouts and typical error conditions.

Comment: used the second one. worked like a charm. That example taought me what I was doing wrong. Thank you.

Comment: quick addition to question. What if I wanted to use https?

Comment: just setting the port will assume https. Nice! Thanks again.

Comment: ok this is working great. But heres an addition. what if i want to actually chack a certain page. Not just www.google.com but www.google.com/anypage.php and if it matters i am using an alternate port

Comment: Just use `http.head("/anypage.php")`