# Net::http check actual page

Tags: ruby

Ok so I got some help [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16444194/ruby-checking-to-see-if-website-exists) checking and actual host to see if its available. I then wrote this.

I pass it for my server `www.myhost.com` and port 81. Works perfect. But what if I want to actually check a page. `www.myhost.com/anypage.php?` Not sure but I think the problem lies with the alternate port.

```
def server_up(server, port)
  http = Net::HTTP.start(server, port, {open_timeout: 5, read_timeout: 5})
  response = http.head("/")
  response.code == "200"
rescue Timeout::Error, SocketError
  false
end
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you're looking for? Are you saying you just want to check if the server responds to `www.myhost.com/anypage.php` with `200`?

Comment: exactly!  the code I posted will tell me if the sites up, but I want to append a page to it. i want to check an actual page in the site? if in the server variable i put www.myhost.com/mypage.php it returns false. other wise it works with just the www.myhost.com returning true.

Comment: @SeeleyBoothe I've just answered your question from yesterday.

Comment: Why don't you specify the path in the `head` call?

Comment: can you add one more tag `Net::HTTP`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As tadman mentioned in the comments, you could modify your method to accept an optional path argument (below). You may want to rename the method, though, since it will no longer simply check if the server is up, but rather, also if the page exists.

```
def server_up(server, port, path="")
  http = Net::HTTP.start(server, port, {open_timeout: 5, read_timeout: 5})
  response = http.head("/#{path}")
  response.code == "200"
rescue Timeout::Error, SocketError
  false
end
```

Comment: as you are right with that. problem is the server I am working against will return with "script not found" and the path where it was supposed to be. So where I am dead ending is that it won't just return false because the server is actually up but the page isnt there?